# Populate array with integer sequence using for loop without crashing Chrome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, for-loop, crash

I want to populate an array with all of the possible integers between 1 000 000 and 10 000 000. When I run the loop below, it crashes the chrome tab. How can I accomplish this?

```js
var arrList = [];
var list;

function gen() {
  for (var i = 1000000; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arrList.push(i);
  }
}

gen();
list = arrList.join(' '); // This line causes the crash
console.log(list);
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

I'm guessing the code is being treated as malicious, since you're trying to eat up a ton of memory.

Comment: @ChrisV I'm creating a list of possible phone numbers in a single area code. Starting with (nnn) 100-0000.

Comment: Same question again :)

Comment: @ChrisV A girl I know said that if I could guess her number, she'd confirm it.

Comment: It doesn't crash my Chrome tab.

Comment: @Barmar You're right! I thought it was the `push`ing that crashed the tab, but it was the `join`ing which I didn't include when I posted. I have updated the code to include everything in my script. Do you now get the same result?

Comment: Does it still crash if you take out the `console.log()`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it crashes at the `join`. See where I commented in the code? I can `console.log(arrList)` and it will print successfully. But when I `join`, it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `console.log(list)` that causes the crash. The console can't handle trying to display a string that's 72 MB long.

When I take that line out, the script runs successfully, although it takes several seconds. This alerts `71999999` after 2-3 seconds.

```js
var arrList = [];
var list;

function gen() {
  for (var i = 1000000; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arrList.push(i);
  }
}

gen();
list = arrList.join(' '); 
alert(list.length);
```

Comment: I replied to your last comment while you were creating this answer.

Comment: It doesn't crash there for me. If I remove the `console.log()` it works fine.

Comment: Well, dang. I'll read up on how to record JS performance and see if I can figure out exactly at which point it's crashing for me.

Comment: Do you know any way to record what's going on with the JS and why the tab crashes? After my tab crashes, I am not able to view any JS performance profiles, and I do not see anything on chrome://crashes. I tried checking and unchecking "Automatically send usage statistics and crash reports to Google" in my settings.

Comment: You could try reducing the size of the loop until it doesn't crash. Then you should be able to use the profile tab to see what's happening leading up to the crash.

Comment: I am just going to use another method to show the numbers in groups instead of all at once. Thanks for the guidance.